# SQL Server Bulk Insert "Cannot fetch a row"

Tags: sql-server

I'm having a crazy problem with bulk insert. I'm using a PHP script to create hundreds of small tab-delimited files that are then bulk inserted into SQL Server. Each file is created exactly the same way and overwrites a file, tmp.txt, which is then bulk inserted into the proper table. tmp.txt is tab-delimited and has line feeds and no carriage returns. My bulk insert syntax says:

```
bulk insert RCB from 
'E:\tmp\tmp.txt'
with(rowterminator = '0x0a', fieldterminator = '\t')
```

The bulk insert fails on some files, whether I run it via my script or directly in SSMS, returning this error message:

```
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The 
provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".
```

I've examined a couple of the files that failed and all looks correct. With one of the files, I tried deleting rows from the text file and running the bulk insert statement again. I eventually found out that if I kept just rows 1 through 694, the bulk insert worked. I then figured out the ASCII code of every character in line 695 and there were no odd ones! Only tabs and digits 0-9. This shows the count of each ASCII character code for lines 693 through 697. (Code 9 is a tab; 48-57 are digits 0-9).

```
Array
(
[693] => Array
    (
        [57] => 6
        [52] => 19
        [54] => 19
        [49] => 17
        [9] => 379
        [48] => 80
        [50] => 15
        [56] => 10
        [53] => 13
        [55] => 9
        [51] => 13
    )

[694] => Array
    (
        [57] => 13
        [52] => 12
        [55] => 9
        [53] => 15
        [9] => 379
        [48] => 84
        [49] => 12
        [51] => 25
        [54] => 5
        [50] => 16
        [56] => 3
    )

[695] => Array
    (
        [57] => 11
        [52] => 3
        [56] => 7
        [53] => 4
        [9] => 379
        [48] => 92
        [51] => 11
        [54] => 6
        [50] => 10
        [49] => 5
        [55] => 2
    )

[696] => Array
    (
        [57] => 5
        [53] => 10
        [48] => 86
        [49] => 14
        [9] => 379
        [51] => 15
        [56] => 6
        [54] => 4
        [52] => 11
        [55] => 7
        [50] => 9
    )

[697] => Array
    (
        [57] => 7
        [53] => 8
        [54] => 10
        [9] => 379
        [48] => 92
        [50] => 8
        [51] => 4
        [49] => 13
        [52] => 5
        [56] => 2
    )
```

I'm at a complete loss about what breaks this bulk insert. Any ideas?

Comment: Please show your code!

Comment: Do you mean the PHP code?

Comment: You've tagged the question "php" and started it with "I'm using a PHP script" so I assume it's a problem with PHP

Comment: Perhaps you are running into an overflow issue? You have a lot of columns so it may be a pain to check. Is it the same row that fails every time?

Comment: The problem definitely is not with the PHP script. I've checked the files it's outputting every which way and they are fine. There are no characters besides tabs, line feeds and digits in the files that are failing. It's definitely a glitch with bulk insert.

After some more troubleshooting, I realize I can write any 694 lines from the file I was troubleshooting (it has 8,858 lines total). I ran a PHP script that write lines 2000-2694 to a different file and they bulk inserted fine. When I wrote lines 2000-2695 and tried inserting, it failed. Very weird.

Comment: I just tried the import wizard and it pulled all 8,858 rows into the same table I've been trying to bulk insert the data into without a hitch. This is a real head scratcher.

Comment: Has your file got a trailing row terminator?  In other words, is the last character in the file a line feed?  What happens when you remove it?

Comment: Yes, every file I create has a line feed after the last line of data. I did try removing that. No change. Also, as I noted above, I can write any 694 lines from the file to a different file, with a line feed after the last line of data, and it works just fine. With 695 or more lines, it fails. And the import wizard pulls in all 8,858 rows without a hitch.

Comment: Update:  I tried this on another server. My PHP script creates the table layout and then bulk inserts the files it parses. I took the exact create table syntax from the script, created the table and bulk inserted the same file that was failing on the other server. It went through without a problem. So something has to be set funny on the original server I was using. The mystery deepens.